# How to sum corresponding elements of two RDD[Int]s?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to make a very simple operation.
I need to realise an addition between 2 vectors, for {1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8,9,10} I want to obtain the vector {7,9,11,13,15}.
The 2 vectors are represented in my code by two RDD[Int].

```
val v1 = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5))
val v2 = sc.parallelize(List(6,7,8,9,10))
```

I know that I can't browse a RDD when I'm mapping another one and because of this I have no idea of how to realise such a simple operation.
How could I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use `zip` operator.

Quoting [RDD.zip](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@zip[U](other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U])(implicitevidence$10:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(T,U)]):

> **zip[U](other: RDD[U])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[(T, U)]** Zips this RDD with another one, returning key-value pairs with the first element in each RDD, second element in each RDD, etc.

In your case, it'd be as follows:

```
val zipped = v1 zip v2 // <-- you may want to use v1.zip(v2) instead to keep types
zipped.map { case (x, y) => x + y }    
scala> zipped.map { case (x, y) => x + y }.foreach(println)
11
13
9
15
7
```

---

As a bonus, please consider Spark SQL where such simple operations (like `foreach(println)`) would look as follows:

```
val sums = zipped.map { case (x, y) => x + y }.toDF("sum")
scala> sums.show
+---+
|sum|
+---+
|  7|
|  9|
| 11|
| 13|
| 15|
+---+
```

And you've got sorting "for free" *(!)*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your 2 `RDD`s have the same size, you can do:

```
val res: RDD[Int] = v1.zip(v2).map { case (a, b) => a + b }
```